# doesn't detect memcached failure

Tags: libmemcache, libmemcached

i am using libmemcached-0.32. I set the behavior flags as below

> memcached_behavior_set(memcached, MEMCACHED_BEHAVIOR_SERVER_FAILURE_LIMIT, 5);
>   memcached_behavior_set(memcached, MEMCACHED_BEHAVIOR_AUTO_EJECT_HOSTS, 1);

but when one of the two memcached hosts went down, it does not eject it.

I need some sort of switch over mechanism, like if one server goes down libmemcached should go on another server to get/set requests.

what should I do ?